# Improving Entity Framework Performance when selecting large amount of related objects?

Tags: vb.net, performance, entity-framework

I'm using EF6, when i try to select a fairly large amount of objects (around 1000) the performance is terrible. Is there anything i can do to improve performance? I'm using Lazy Loading.

I have considered modifying the query to select just the fields i need for this particular function, or selecting into an anonymous type and returning that back and only select into the BI.Lead object when that is actually needed. I just don't understand how that would impact performance.  As i understand it, with lazy loading should the query to return the property not be executed until the property is requested?

**Sample Code**

```
    Dim db As New EFDB.EFDBContainer
    Dim one As IQueryable(Of EFDB.Lead) = db.Leads.AsNoTracking.Where(Function(c) c.ClientID = ClientID And c.softDelete = False And c.State = ParamState).OrderBy(Function(c) c.DateCreate())
    Dim two As List(Of EFDB.Lead) = one.ToList()
    Dim three As IEnumerable(Of BI.Lead) = two.Select(Function(p) New BI.Lead(p, db))
    Return three.ToList

 myDataRepeater.Datasource = three.Tolist()
 myDataRepeater.Databind()
```

Notice that i have to select the EF object results *into* the BI.Lead object; as the caller is expecting a list of BI.Lead objects. I've already significantly improved performance by passing in the existing DB context to the select function.

**BI.Lead**

```
Public Sub New()
    _cxt = New EFDB.EFDBContainer
    _person = New EFDB.Lead
End Sub

Public Sub New(EntityObject As EFDB.Lead, cxt As EFDB.EFDBContainer)
    _person = EntityObject
    _cxt = cxt
End Sub

Public Sub New(ID As Guid)
    If Not IsNothing(ID) Then
        If IsNothing(_cxt) Then _cxt = New EFDB.EFDBContainer
        If IsNothing(_person) Then
            _person = _cxt.Leads.Find(ID)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub New(ID As Guid)
    If Not IsNothing(ID) Then
        If IsNothing(_cxt) Then _cxt = New EFDB.EFDBContainer
        If IsNothing(_person) Then
            _person = _cxt.Leads.Find(ID)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private _cxt As EFDB.EFDBContainer
Private _person As EFDB.Lead

Protected Overridable Overloads Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    If disposing Then
        If Not IsNothing(_cxt) Then
            _cxt.SaveChanges()
            _cxt.Dispose()
            _person = Nothing
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Overloads Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    Dispose(True)
    GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property AppointmentDate As Date?
    Get
        If _person.Appointments.Count() < 1 Then Return Nothing
        Dim _apt = _person.Appointments.FirstOrDefault()
        If Not IsNothing(_apt) Then Return _apt.AppointmentDate
        Return Nothing
    End Get
End Property

   Public Property EmailAddress As String
    Get
        If Not IsNothing(_person.EmailAddress) Then
            Return _person.EmailAddress
        Else
            Return String.Empty
        End If
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        If Not IsNothing(_person) Then
            _person.EmailAddress = value
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

Returning the first one.ToList() takes only 5-10 seconds with 1500 records.

Returning the next three.ToList() takes roughly 20-30 seconds with same records.

Finally the databinding takes the longest at 25-30 seconds with same records.

In the datarepeater i directly cast the container.dataItem to try and improve performance. I know Eval() causes a big performance hit. Its done this way because i need to pull some values in javascript. Is there a better way for this?

```
<%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, BI.Lead).ID%>
```

Comment: You are saying the performance is terrible. How long it takes to execute `one.ToList()` and how long `three.ToList()`?

Comment: Could you provide the code which use that data? Because if for instance you use foreach on that data and using that AppointmentDate property you get 2 request to database for each person. (1000 persons = 2000 separate db requests)

Comment: What is `_person`? It would be better to show the full class definitions (`EFDB.Lead.Lead` and  `BI.Lead`). This can probably be simplified considerably.